# What is the best approach for showing large results from Amazon DynamoDB?

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have around 150.000 rows of subscribers answers in a table, and I need to provide a way to let a user select a winner.

I have all this implemented in MS SQL, but because we're having a bit more traffic that  expected, I thought it was a good idea to move to a Amazon DynamoDB environment for this particular part (handling subscribers)

in MS SQL I have a SP that is something like:

```
SELECT s.name, s.guid
FROM calendars c
INNER JOIN challenges cl on cl.calendar_id = c.calendar_id
INNER JOIN challenge_answers ca on ca.calendar_id = c.calendar_id
INNER JOIN subscribers s on s.calendar_id = c.calendar_id
WHERE 
      c.calendar_id = 9 and 
      cl.day = 15 and
      ca.correct = 1 and 
      s.email not like '%@mydomain.com'
ORDER BY s.name DESC;
```

and using LINQ I end up with `.Take(25).Skip(page);`

I understand that `INNER JOIN`'s in Amazon DynamoDB are not a viable option, so I added more fields to the `subscribers` table, witch include all other fields so I can simply have only one table and each item contains everything for the query.

What should be the best approach using Amazon DynamoDB to retrieve only a partial group and safely skip "pages"?

Comment: I understand the paging part of your question, but the use of the word "winner" makes me wonder what you are really doing.  Are you just trying to select a random item and you think paging is the means to the end?  Or does the user really need to be able to page through all of them and manually select the winner? (Doesn't sound like a very fair drawing)

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB is not really designed to skip pages, but rather get items based on their keys. The query like features is fairly limited and is applicable only for keys (hash or range) with basic operations. As well, you can use the keys of the defined indexes, but same limitations apply there. Here is some additional information about [Query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html).

Regarding pagination, DynamoDB doesn't offer a cursor, so if you start iterating over a set of keys you need to read all items until LastEvaluatedKey value returned in each response in null. At the moment, there is no built in support of skipping to a specific page. You can emulate this by building index tables for pages, so then you can fetch the items of a page directly from that index. Chris Moyer suggest a solution [here](http://blog.coredumped.org/2012/01/amazon-dynamodb.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [LINQ2DynamoDB](http://linq2dynamodb.codeplex.com/) DataContext. It caches DynamoDB query results in an in-memory cache (MemcacheD), which greatly improves performance for sorting/paging scenarios in ASP.Net. There's also a custom [ASP.Net DataSource](http://linq2dynamodb.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Sources/Linq2DynamoDb.AspNet.DataSource/DynamoDbDataSource.cs) implementation there, so you can turn the paging on with no single line of code.